# koush/ion Crash in Android gradle 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-ion

I upgraded the build Gradle to 4.1.1 and the app is crashed. Please check the following log. Is there any solution for it? I opened an [issue](https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/944) in Github.

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError
       at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.write(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:492)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handleHandshakeStatus(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:378)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handshake(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:182)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.tryHandshake(AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.java:89)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware$2.onConnectCompleted(AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.java:106)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSocketMiddleware.lambda$getSocket$3$AsyncSocketMiddleware(AsyncSocketMiddleware.java:217)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.http.-$$Lambda$AsyncSocketMiddleware$glazjOxu-iNIRY4N890Wl1ngyGo.onCompleted(:12)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.lambda$setCallback$0(SimpleFuture.java:212)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$SimpleFuture$h_gK5Y1XHZI1H8JTE2xOg4dXbp8.onCompleted(:2)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture$FutureCallsite.loop(SimpleFuture.java:130)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:153)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:191)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:174)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$VNAuWcttAhMr3VsWCERbmWE6yR0.success(:2)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.lambda$success$4(SimpleFuture.java:279)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$SimpleFuture$DxIsaj7NQi76eWgOKS4iviWPLV0.onCompleted(:4)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture$FutureCallsite.loop(SimpleFuture.java:130)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:153)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:191)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:178)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.http.-$$Lambda$cBC5du-82c5EcL72rP5wNK7Y2Y4.onConnectCompleted(:2)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:896)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:717)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:46)
       at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$11.run(AsyncServer.java:671)
```

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: It's fixed by upgrading the Ion library to 3.1.0